# How do I get a login page to work as intended?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, authentication

I have this code (html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    .container {
      width: 300px;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 8px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px 0;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input[type="submit"] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="submit"]:hover {
      background-color: #0056b3;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="loginBtn" name ="login_Btn">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have this (.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "my_db";

    /* You should enable error reporting for mysqli before attempting to make a connection */
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    /* Set the desired charset after establishing a connection */
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');

    printf("Success... %s\n <br>", mysqli_get_host_info($conn));

    if(isset($_POST['login_Btn'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM my_db.logindetails WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $resultPassword = $row['password'];
                if($password == $resultPassword) {
                    header('Location:index.html');
                } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('Login unsuccesful');</script>";
                    }
            }
    }

?>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that whenboth the username and password is wrong then I can't get a javascript alert popup that says "Login unsuccesful". It only works when the username is correct and the password is wrong. Further I want to make a login page that sends e-mail with a code so that the user must prove that he has access to his e-mail account every time he wants to login.
Please help me with this project.

Comment: *"The problem is that whenboth the username and password is wrong"* ... Your current code never checks for when the username is not in the db. Thus your while loop only iterates if the username exists, but not when it doesnt. As opposed to a while loop, since the result will only be one or no rows (right?), use an if statement. That way you can have an else.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "my_db";

    /* You should enable error reporting for mysqli before attempting to make a connection */
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    /* Set the desired charset after establishing a connection */
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');

    printf("Success... %s\n <br>", mysqli_get_host_info($conn));

    if(isset($_POST['login_Btn'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM my_db.logindetails WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

       
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $resultPassword = $row['password'];
                if($password == $resultPassword) {
                    header('Location:index.html');
                } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('Login unsuccessful');</script>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Login unsuccessful');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. Now I just need to fix so the page sends an e-mail with a code when I try to login.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).